# r markdown could not find function "%>%" error

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am working on the google data analytics certificate and kind of just messing around. But I was trying to create a markdown in r with some code chunks. Everything is working except one chunk. When I run that chunk in r console it works just fine, but when I run knitr I get an error.

The code chunk is as follows:

```
average_mass<-penguins %>% select(species,body_mass_g) %>% drop_na() %>% group_by(species) %>% summarize(avg_body_mass=mean(body_mass_g))

ggplot(average_mass,aes(species,avg_body_mass,fill=species))+geom_col()+
  labs(title="Penguins: Average Body Mass By species",caption="Gentoo is the Largest")
```

but when I run knitr the result is this:

### Error in penguins %>% select(species, body_mass_g) %>% drop_na() %>% group_by(species) %>% : could not find function "%>%"

### Error in ggplot(average_mass, aes(species, avg_body_mass, fill = species)): object 'average_mass' not found

Obviously since I'm just messing around its not a big deal but was kind of curious if there was a way to resolve this issue??

Comment: You need to include `library(tidyverse)` in your RMarkdown document before you use this code.

Comment: did you load the libraries, i.e. `library(dplyr)` in the chunks?